# Unable to see the newly created branch after cloning my own git repository on my laptop

Tags: git, branch, clone

I have setup a secure git repo setup on my desktop which I am able to access and clone from anywhere. However after cloning the repository I can only see the master branch and not the new dev branch that I have created on my desktop (which is my git server). Just to be clear the dev branch on the server does not have any data yet, but I was atleast expecting to see that it exists, after cloning that repo on my laptop.

Please help!!

Answer (score 2):

After you do the clone, do:

```
git checkout -b dev origin/dev
```

This will create and switch to the dev branch.

If you are talking about having created the branch on the clone repo, do

```
git checkout <branch_name>
```

to switch to the branch.

Comment: But I don't wanna create a dev branch on my laptop. I just want to clone it from the git server, where an empty dev branch already exists. Hope I'm making sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can see all the existing branches with :

```
git branch -a
```

For a basic repository (master branch only), the output is :

```
* master                  ---> local master branch
  remotes/origin/master   ---> remote master branch
```

After a simple `git branch dev`, the output of `git branch -a` should be :

```
  dev                     ---> local dev branch
* master                  ---> local master branch
  remotes/origin/master   ---> remote master branch
```

If you want to create a branch on your remote repository :

```
git push origin <local branch name>:<remote branch name>
```

Or if you want to keep the name of the local branch :

```
git push origin <local branch name>
```

And `git branch -a` should give :

```
  dev                     ---> local dev branch
* master                  ---> local master branch
  remotes/origin/dev      ---> remote dev branch
  remotes/origin/master   ---> remote master branch
```

Comment: Got it..thanks! I combined what you said to see all the branches, and combined it with @manojlds' solution to checkout dev branch. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to push your branch up first from the original repo:

```
git push origin branchname
```

Then fetch from the new clone:

```
git fetch origin #origin is optional if that's the only remote you have
```

Now create and checkout the branch locally:

```
git checkout -t origin/branchname
```